# Am I approaching a probability problem correctly

Tags: statistics

> There are $76$ balls labeled $A$, $89$ balls labeled $B$, and $51$ balls labeled $C$. What is the probability of pulling 4 balls where two balls are of one matching type (i.e. two $A$'s) and the other two balls are of another matching type (i.e. two $A$'s)?

My approach is as follows:

$$\frac{(AABB + AACC + BBCC)} {^{216}C_{4}}$$

Therefore

$$\frac{(^{76}C_2 \cdot ^{89}C_2) + (^{76}C_2 \cdot ^{51}C_2) + (^{89}C_2 \cdot ^{51}C_2)}{^{216}C_4}$$

Am I correct or missing something?

Comment: That looks plausible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct since you've accounted for all such cases (2 A's and 2 B's, two A's and two C's, and finally two B's and two C's) and added the total probability together. This is assuming you don't care about silly things such as whether the balls are pulled in consecutive order and such.